# Is keeping white/grey hair/beard haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hair, beard, dyeing-hair

I would like to extend this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67376/the-obligation-on-dying-hair) (unanswered)
I read [here](https://zinaidabunaser.com/2011/11/16/grey-hair-in-islam-rulings-and-sunnahs/#:%7E:text=Firstly%3A%20Dyeing%20grey%20hairs%20is,in%20the%20beard%2C%20for%20men.) that,

> “The Jews and the Christians do not dye their hair, so be different
> from them.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3275; Muslim, 2103).
>
> إِنَّ الْيَهُودَ وَالنَّصَارَى لاَ يَصْبُغُونَ، فَخَالِفُوهُمْ

So is keeping grey/white hair not permissible in Islam ? I couldn't find any more references.

Comment: It's not haram but the Sunna is to dye your hair just like the Prophet said

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is dyeing hair not obligatory?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67376/why-is-dyeing-hair-not-obligatory)

Answer (score -1):

Not every hadith makes a compulsory rule. I consider this hadith outdated because Christians and Jews may nowadays also dye their hair and maybe it has also lost importance to have a different outfit.

Comment: Dyeing hair here means to dye the gray hair that has emerged from aging, and most Christians and Jews don't actually dye their aging gray hair. It's not referring to teenagers dyeing their hairs green/yellow/brown/etc.

Comment: I know Silvio Berlusconi and Donald Trump but no Muslim around me who have dyed their gray hair- me, either..